# .NET - RSA не может декодировать

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

```
    static string Encrypt(string str)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(RSA.Encrypt(bytes, true));
    }
    static string Decrypt(string str)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(RSA.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(str), true));
    }
```

Ошибка идёт при RSA.Decrypt

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаёте в двух методах два *разных* экземпляра `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. У них, вполне естественно, *разные* внутренние ключи.

Кроме того, вы используете `Encoding.Default`. Кодировка по умолчанию *разная* на *разных* машинах. **Никогда** не используйте в своём коде Default-кодировку!

Если в обоих методах использовать один и тот же экземпляр крипто-провайдера и какую-нибудь юникодную кодировку, то код работает:

```
// поле класса
static RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

static string Encrypt(string str)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(RSA.Encrypt(bytes, true));
}

static string Decrypt(string str)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RSA.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(str), true));
}


var source = "Привет";
var encrypted = Encrypt(source);
var decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted);

Console.WriteLine(source);
Console.WriteLine(decrypted);
Console.WriteLine(decrypted == source); // True
```

---

Смысл шифрования в том, чтобы передавать данные из одного места в другое, с одного компьютера на другой, например, по сети. Экземпляр класса передать нельзя. А вот ключи - можно.

В документации [RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8) есть пример, как экспортировать и импортировать параметры провайдера.

Например, можно сделать так:

```
static (string, RSAParameters) Encrypt(string str)
{
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
        var data = rsa.Encrypt(bytes, true);
        var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

        return (encrypted, parameters);
    }
}

static string Decrypt(string str, RSAParameters parameters)
{
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rsa.ImportParameters(parameters);

        var data = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
        var bytes = rsa.Decrypt(data, true);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
}

var source = "Привет";
var (encrypted, parameters) = Encrypt(source);
var decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, parameters);

Console.WriteLine(source);
Console.WriteLine(decrypted);
Console.WriteLine(decrypted == source); // True
```

Из метода `Encrypt` возвращаем зашифрованную строку и параметры провайдера в виде кортежа.

В метод `Decrypt`, соответственно, тоже нужно передавать эти параметры.

Этот ключ, по идее, нужно сгенерировать один раз и где-то надёжно хранить.